# Vacuum of a QFT in flat spacetime from an experimental point of view

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, vacuum

Consider a QFT in **flat** spacetime from the point of view of an inertial observer with coordinates $(t,{\vec x})$. Suppose this guy expands a quantum field $\hat{\phi}$ in two distinct complete sets of orthonormal modes $\{f_i(t,\vec{x})\}$ and $\{g_\alpha(t,\vec{x})\}$ as follows
$$\hat{\phi}(t,{\vec x})=\sum_i\left(\hat{a}_if_i(t,\vec{x})+\hat{a}_i^\dagger f_i^*(t,\vec{x})\right)=\sum_\alpha\left(\hat{b}_\alpha g_\alpha(t,\vec{x})+\hat{b}_\alpha^\dagger g_\alpha^*(t,\vec{x})\right)$$
with the following commutation relations
$$[\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j^\dagger]=\delta_{ij}, [\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j]=[\hat{a}_i^\dagger,\hat{a}_j^\dagger]=0,
\\
[\hat{b}_\alpha,\hat{b}_\beta^\dagger]=\delta_{\alpha\beta}, [\hat{b}_\alpha,\hat{b}_\beta]=[\hat{b}_\alpha^\dagger,\hat{b}_\beta^\dagger]=0.$$

In the above, the '$i$'-type indices could be the wavevector indices ${\vec k}$ (as in the case of plane wave modes), and '$\alpha$'-type indices could be something different.

Thus the operators $\hat{b}_\alpha$ will be related to the operators $\hat{a}_i$ by bogoliubov transformation, and if $\hat{a}_i|0_f\rangle=0$ and $\hat{b}_\alpha|0_g\rangle=0$, it is easy to show that $$\langle 0_f|\hat{b}^\dagger_\alpha\hat{b}_\alpha|0_f\rangle\neq 0.$$

Therefore, even for an inertial observer in flat spacetime, the notion of vacuum does not seem to be unique. However, if we say that the vacuum state is one for which $\langle H\rangle$ is minimum, we have a unique vacuum state and a unique mode expansion. In flat space, this turns out to be an expansion in terms of plane wae modes. See the answer [Interpretation of the nonuniqueness of vacuum of QFT in flat spacetime for a given inertial observer; No Lorentz transformation; No accelerated motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/634175/164488) by @ChiralAnomaly.

Now, whether a state contains particles or not is an experimental question. Suppose we have agreed to define our vacuum as a state in which $\langle H\rangle$ is minimized i.e. we have agreed to use the plane wave modes. But how does the detector know what definition of vacuum to use?

Comment: You can relate the two orthonormal modes using Bogolyubov transformations

Comment: @KP99 I have completely rephrased the question. Thanks for your comment.